# how to hook checkout pane defined in another module?

Tags: commerce

I try to make a small change to Drupal Commerce Coupon pane (add a div to it). I tried to hook this function:

```
    function commerce_coupon_pane_checkout_form($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
              // Allow to replace pane content with ajax calls.
              $pane_form = array(
                '#prefix' => '<div id="commerce-checkout-coupon-ajax-wrapper">',
                '#suffix' => '</div>',
              );
        (..)
}
```

To do this I created a function in my module:

```
function <mymodule>_form_commerce_coupon_pane_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="collapsable-panel"><p>You have coupon? Add it here.</p>' + $form['#prefix'];
        $form['#suffix'] = $form['#suffix'] + '</div>';
    }
```

but it do not work. I think that there should be other way to hook checkout pane but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. 
Hooking Drupal Commerce panes works quite diffrent than hooking functions from other modules. 
At begining: *form* in commerce_coupon_pane_checkout_form is confusing - this function in fact doesn't create form but is "added" as a fieldset to one big checkout form. And of course it cannot be hooked.

What do you need to change behaviour of panes defined in Drupal Commerce and other commerce modules:

1. Read: [Checkout info hooks](https://drupalcommerce.org/developer-guide/core-architecture/info-hooks/checkout-info-hooks)
2. create `function <mymodule>_commerce_checkout_pane_info_alter`
3. Inside this function override pane settings using: `$checkout_panes[<pane_name>]['callbacks']['checkout_form'] = <your_custom_pane_function>`
4. create `<your_custom_pane_function>($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order)`
5. Probably there will be need to call existing implementation of pane and change some configuration of form returned form this existing implementation.

and thats all :)

Answer (score 0):

`commerce_checkout_form_PAGE` is a form ID. Use it inside of `HOOK_form_FORM_ID_alter` to edit a particular page of the checkout process. Like so:

```
function MYMODULE_form_commerce_checkout_form_checkout_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="collapsable-panel"><p>You have coupon? Add it here.</p>' + $form['#prefix'];
    $form['#suffix'] = $form['#suffix'] + '</div>';
}
```

Alternatively, you can also do a generic alter and check the build info in `$form_state`:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['build_info']['base_form_id'] == 'commerce_checkout_form') {
    // We're in checkout.
    $form[PANE_ID] ... 
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried that but it doesn't work.